# Google meet on Firefox: mic slow to start transmitting

Tags: firefox, microphone

Running Ubuntu 18. I switched from Chrome to Firefox as my primary browser a while back. When I join a google meet, the webcam transmits to the other attendees immediately but it takes a while for the mic to start transmitting. What's odd is the "vu meter" in my "self view" shows that the mic is getting a signal... it takes 5-10 seconds before it starts transmitting... after that things work great.

I've swapped it with a different webcam model and saw no change in behavior.
This is still happening on the latest version of firefox (77.0.1)

Comment: Do you see anything suspicious in the web console? (Ctrl+Shift+K)

Comment: I have the same issue, as well as one of my colleagues. It happens about 50% of the time I open a Meet window. Other times, audio works immediately.